# unable to set rabbitmq lazy queue

Tags: rabbitmq

I have referred the link https://www.rabbitmq.com/lazy-queues.html here and set the rabbitmq queue to lazy queue using the following command

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy Lazy "^lazy-queue$" '{"queue-mode":"lazy"}' --apply-to queues
```

However, when checking it using the command  `curl -u guest:guest 'localhost:15672/api/queues'` it still shows the default queue as below

```
"mode":"default" .
```

How do I set the queue to lazy queue in rabbitmq. Could someone please help

Comment: What is the name of your queue?

Comment: We have multiple queues created. Do we have to set it for each queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Policy](https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html) defines a rule that applies to all queues whose name matches a particular pattern.

Let's have a closer look at the command you've copied:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy Lazy "^lazy-queue$" '{"queue-mode":"lazy"}' --apply-to queues
```

- We are creating or updating a policy called "Lazy"; as far as I know, this can be any name you like
- The pattern we want it to apply to is `^lazy-queue$`; this is a regular expression which only matches the exact name "lazy-queue"
- The configuration we want to apply is to set "queue-mode" to "lazy"

So, if you want it to apply to multiple queues, you need to adjust the policy to apply to those queues. For instance, you could apply it to all queues whose names begin "lazy-":

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy Lazy "^lazy-" '{"queue-mode":"lazy"}' --apply-to queues
```

Or any name that ends in a four-digit number:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy Lazy "-[0-9]{4}$" '{"queue-mode":"lazy"}' --apply-to queues
```

Or just apply to every queue:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy LazyEverything ".*" '{"queue-mode":"lazy"}' --apply-to queues
```

Comment: now I get it how to enable lazy queue. Thank you

Comment: I was able to enable the lazy queue for a queue in idle state but not for a queue which is in running state. When I run the following command "rabbitmqctl set_policy Lazy "queue name" '{"queue-mode":"lazy"}' --apply-to queues" it shows the message as below

Setting policy "Lazy" for pattern "queue name" to "{"queue-mode":"lazy"}" with priority "0" for vhost "/" ...

But when I check using the curl command the mode is still set to default for the respective queue .